# What does it mean to say an ODE state vector is finite dimensional?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, intuition

I recently read this on Wikipedia, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

> They belong to the class of systems with the functional state, i.e.
>   partial differential equations (PDEs) which are infinite dimensional,
>   as opposed to ordinary differential equations (ODEs) having a finite
>   dimensional state vector.

What does this mean? Why are PDEs infinite and ODEs finite?

Comment: An ODE can certainly have infinite dimensional state. I think what they mean is, in a *typical* ODE, state is finite-dimensional, whereas in the type of equation described in that article, $x'(t)$ depends on the entire trajectory of $x$ up to time $t$, thus necessarily on an infinite dimensional object.

Comment: That helps some, but what does it even mean in the first place to talk about the dimensionality of the state vector? I thought I understood this, but I realize I don't.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "the state vector". If you mean "the thing that $f$ depends on", then it's certainly infinite dimensional in that $f$ is defined on an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: So if I have an ODE like $\partial_t f(x) = 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then that ODE is infinite dimensional because it's over the reals?

Comment: No. The real numbers form a one dimensional vector space. The space of possible trajectories of a function $x$ up to time $t$ are an infinite dimensional vector space. You need to look up the notion of a vector space and understand the concept of dimension of a vector space.

Comment: I do understand vector spaces. I don't understand how ODE and PDE can have state spaces that are finite/infinite. In the example I just gave, I thought the phase space was infinite because maybe you need a dimension for every point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood. If by $\partial_tf(x)=0$ you mean $\forall x \partial_t f(t, x)=0$, then yes, the state of the system at time $t$ is the function $f(t, \cdot)$ and is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Yes, I meant the whole real line is stationary. That helps, thanks. So when would an ODE ever be finite?

Comment: In most classical cases. Like say $x'(t)=x(t)$. State is one dimensional.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the Cauchy problem $y' = Ay$ with $y(0) = {y_0}$, with $A$ is an operator.
When we talk about ODE, $A$ is aways a matrix which acts from $R^n$ to $R^m$ (finite dimension operator), for example dynamical system, but in pde theory the operator $A$ is an operator who defined on infinite dimensional space for example Laplacian, derevative operator, elliptique operator are always defined on some functional spaces ( Soboev spaces, $C^m$ ....etc).